# Select all data in a column of a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to update a record in the database and I do want to update all records that is in the datagridview from value `'Pending'` to value `'Cleared'` by selecting the borrow ID in the WHERE condition of my query.

```
    private void UpdatePaymentStat()
    {
        cn.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string borrow = gunaDataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblBorrowedBook SET paymentStatus = 'Cleared' WHERE borrowID = @borrowID", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borrowID", borrow);
        }
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

And this is my btnSubmit

```
    private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (MyMessageBox.ShowMessage("Proceed processing the payment made by " + lblName.Text + "?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblPayment VALUES (@borrowID, @studentID, @totalPayment, @paymentDate, @description)", cn);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", lblStudentID.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPayment", lblTotalAmount.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentDate", dtPaymentDate.Value);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borrowID", gunaDataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", gunaDataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                    UpdatePaymentStat();
                    frmissue.LoadPending();

                    popupNotifier.ContentText = "Payment has been successfully processed!";
                    popupNotifier.Popup();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code works when inserting all the rows from datagridview to the table `tblPayment` but in updating the column `paymentStatus` in table `tblBorrowedBook`, only the selected row is updating.

**How can I update all the datagridview rows value?**

Comment: Why aren't you using a DataAdapter and putting results into a DataTable.  Then make the datatable the DataSource for the DGV.  Then you put changes into the DataTable instead of the DGV (the DGV datasource in the table so it will get updated).  Then the adapter will track changes and when an update is done to table the database will get updated.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jdweng i still haven't tried that since I am still new to programming, I'll try to learn how it works